# Word vba - if cursor is in cell / bookmark - run code

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a template document which contains several sections and a few tables. 
The thing is, I'm trying to insert a drop-down list inside on of the cells in the table. 
And for a drop-down list to work, the document needs to be protected. But if I protect the entire section the table is in, the entire table is protected.

So, I was wondering if there's a way of executing a macro code IF the user clicks on the drop-down list? The code would then protect the document, making the control actually work, then select a choice and when the user clicks outside of the field, the document should get unprotected.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

There is actually a WindowSelectionChange event in Word VBA that you can use.  It is described in the Word VBA help file under "Using Events with the Application Object".

The trick is to assign your application to a variable in a class module (I've named mine EventClassModule) using the WithEvents keyword:

```
Public WithEvents App As Word.Application
```

Then in your ordinary Document Open event, you can initialize the variable to the current Application:

```
Dim oEvents As New EventClassModule
Private Sub Document_Open()
    Set oEvents.App = Word.Application
End Sub
```

Back in the EventClassModule, you use the WindowSelectionChange event to check if the selection is a table:

```
Private Sub App_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
    If Sel.Information(wdWithInTable) And ThisDocument.ProtectionType = wdNoProtection Then
        ThisDocument.Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields
    ElseIf ThisDocument.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
        ThisDocument.Unprotect
    End If
End Sub
```

This code will be called whenever the cursor changes location.  I tested it and it's a little finicky (the oEvents object has a tendency to become uninitialized for some reason), but hopefully this will be a start for your solution.

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly. 
Where's the
"Public WithEvents App as Word.Application" supposed to be?

I've inserted the code in the middle in the Document_Open event. 
And I created a EventClassModule with the bottom code as you stated. But the first line? Where to put it?

And another thing, is it possible to trigger the code only when the cursor selects a particular bookmark? Because the drop-down fields actually have a bookmark name "Dropdown1" and "Dropdown2". Only these should (preferrably) trigger the code to protect the document. :)

Comment: Pretty sure I've done this correctly, but the WindowSelectionChange doesn't seem to fire at all. That's a real shame really.

Comment: The "Public WithEvents App as Word.Application" goes at the top of the class module EventClassModule -- it is a member variable of the class.  

So in the Document_Open event you're instantiating the class and setting the member variable to the current application.  (I don't know why they mad eit this complicated)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a drop-down box from the forms toolbar, you could use a ComboBox from the control toolbar.  Then you could use the ComboBox click event.  You could also attach code to the GotFocus/LostFocus event for when the user clicks outside of the ComboBox.

Comment: Well, the thing is, this is a template for a report and the drop-down menu is supposed to let the user select the level of conficiality. And whatever the user may pick, should end up as plain text in the document. And the drop-down-list shouldn't be visible at print either.