# Move cursor before formatting in word, programmatically

Tags: vba, ms-word

In a macro, I'm using

```
x.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
```

in order to highlight the current formfield that a userform is editing, because the default selection doesn't show up well.

if I use `Application.Selection.StartOf` then the cursor returns to before the formfield which is what I want.

However the styling gets applied to any text that gets typed.

Is there a way to set the cursor to "before" the styling, so any text entered would be before the style marker? Or do I need to make assumptions on the current text style and set the text at that position to `wdAuto`?

I.E. if this was pseudo HTML(xml) I want

```
<div>XXXX<span color=green><Input id=blah></input></span></div>
```

as opposed to

```
<div><span color=green>XXXX<Input id=blah></input></span></div>
```

Where XXXX is the cursor position.

```
'Remember the last formatted field on select, lets us fix it when the userform is closed.
Dim prevField As formField

Function SelectField(ByVal neww As formField)
If Not prevField Is Nothing Then
    prevField.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdAuto
End If
neww.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
neww.Select
Application.Selection.StartOf
Application.Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdAuto
Set prevField = neww
End Function
```

This example doesn't work. it still has any written text as green.

Comment: The FormField's range has the colour you give it. If you want another colour you must be outside its range or you should find an event that triggers code that changes the colour. Content controls offer such an event. Try ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add wdContentControlRichText, Selection.Range and the Document_ContentControlOnEnter event.

Comment: Here is another solution, probably exactly what you need. I have it at the top of the right column, next to your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043307/word-vba-if-cursor-is-in-cell-bookmark-run-code?rq=1

Comment: 1. If "ContentControl" is the new way of doing fields, then I can't use it for legacy reasons.
2. I don't understand how that's applicable.

Comment: It's applicable because you need an "event" to do what you want, like "run this code when I click this place". I believe content controls were introduced in 2007, maybe 2010. If your legacy has to go back further the application event described in the link I posted can do the job. An application event must be programmed more precisely than one that affects a single document only, but with its help the range's colour can be changed to wdAuto when you click in your form field.